# Vim airline customise settings

Tags: debugging, vim, vundle, vim-airline

In [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMdaq.jpg) of my vimrc settings, I have installed the plugin vim-airline using vundle. After going through airlines docs, I found the set of lines to customise my airline.

The problem is the ones highlighted in red. The blue highlighted one works fine but the red one does not. The left one is same as right one. I tried using different Unicode symbols but does not work. Any workaround to this situation as this is troubling my OCD :P.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use that plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known issue related to the font (size and family) used in your terminal.

For a better display, you have two solutions:

1. Do not use arrows as separators
2. Configure your terminal emulator to use a patched font with the right size

If you prefer the first solution, make sure you have this code in your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:airline_right_sep = ""
let g:airline_left_sep = ""
```

If you prefer the other solution, take a look at this: https://github.com/powerline/fonts

I have used the Hack font with size 11 for a long time and the arrows are perfectly displayed in my editor...